# Value of member 'FIELDNAME' of an object of type 'TABLENAME' changed. A member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I've a table with ARTIEST_JAAR. (in SQL-Server 2008).
And I want change the value JAAR_TM. What do I wrong?

This is the exception that happened:

> Value of member 'JAAR_TM' of an object of type 'ARTIEST_JAAR' changed.
>   A member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed.
>   Consider adding a new object with new identity and deleting the existing one instead.

```
public void OpslaanJarenActief(int AID_Artiest, int AJaar_Van, int AJaar_Tm)
{
    string sMethodName = "OpslaanJarenActief";

    var qryJarenActief = (from a in FDatabeheer.DataContext.ARTIEST_JAARs
                        where a.ID_ARTIEST == AID_Artiest
                        && a.JAAR_VAN == AJaar_Van
                        select a).SingleOrDefault();
    if (qryJarenActief == null)
    {
        .... then insert....
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            qryJarenActief.ID_ARTIEST = AID_Artiest;
            qryJarenActief.JAAR_VAN = AJaar_Van;
            qryJarenActief.JAAR_TM = AJaar_Tm;
            qryJarenActief.DATUM_MUTATIE = DateTime.Today;
            FDatabeheer.DataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            FLogboek.WriteFoutNaarLogboek(FClassName, sMethodName, "Systeemfout", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: This column is an identity which is an auto-increment generated value that can't be set manually. You can remove the identity from it if you don't need it.

Comment: I didn't have auto-increment fields. This is neither a primary key. The fields ID_ARTIEST and JAAR_VAN are set to the Primary Key.

Comment: Maybe your model is not right. Can you check what is the definition of this column in the model?

Comment: Okay in the model was the definition wrong. But I SQL Server I can change PK field values?! And what is the reason you can change it in LINQ?

Comment: I assume this is not allowed because changing the PK in linq is changing the entity state to "new". I'm not sure that Sql Server is not deleting and creating a new row when you change the PK.

Comment: When the primary key is not linked, then you can do it. I tried it as a test. But thank you for your answer.